# Angular material how to make button same height as input

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this little form containing two fields (in outline appearance) and a button.

```
 <form [formGroup]="filterForm">
      <section>
        <ng-container>
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="mr-1">
            <mat-label>First name</mat-label>
            <input matInput placeholder="First name" formControlName="firstName" autocomplete="off"/>
          </mat-form-field>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container>
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Last name</mat-label>
            <input matInput placeholder="Last name" formControlName="lastName" autocomplete="off"/>
          </mat-form-field>
        </ng-container>

        <button mat-flat-button (click)="filter()" class="bg-rose-500 text-white outline-none transition duration-150 ease-in-out transform hover:scale-105">Filter</button>
      </section>
    </form>
```

I just want to make my button the same height as the fields but as angular material add some padding and margin I can't set the good height (and even if I set manually the same height in px I have a small difference at the top of the button).

Here is a screenshot of my current input & buttons:

[image]

As you can see `the mat-form-field` is way bigger than the "real" field
[image]

Here is a small stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-10-date-range-ptfbwi?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Add to screenshot of currant ui to here

Comment: I've added some screen

Comment: could you give a workable demo like on stackblitz? :)

Comment: Stackblitz added

Comment: Awesome! thanks a lot, I am going to have a look :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing your html, I added the following to your css file (naturally you should add appropriate selector and not use the elements):

```
section {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

button {
  margin-top: 0.3em;
  padding: 1.55em 0;
  line-height: 1.125;
}
```

It does not feel too good but it does feel like angular material is forcing our hands. Anyways I believe the look is like the one you wanted, I am using `em`s as that also seems the unit used by the form fields, so the button should behave pretty consistently in regards to the fields.

Here's the thing in stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-10-date-range-jnkwv2?file=src/app/app.component.css

Comment: Jessy I am aware this is not a very elegant solution, but let me know what you think :)

Comment: ah ok, no worries, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a very annoying issue that is still around at time of writing somehow.
I have come across a quick fix that I use with flex given a situation like below:

```
<form class="flex flex-wrap">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Search</mat-label>
    <input type="search" matInput>
  </mat-form-field>

  <div class="align-button-with-input">
    <button mat-flat-button type="submit">
      Submit
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I use the following CSS:

```css
.flex > .align-button-with-input {
  padding-bottom: 1.34375em;
}

.align-button-with-input > .mat-mdc-button-base {
  height: max(36px, 100%);
}
```

Or SCSS:

```scss
.flex { 
  > .align-button-with-input {
    padding-bottom: 1.34375em;

    > .mat-mdc-button-base {
      height: max(36px, 100%);
    }
  }
}
```

This has the effect of making the button aligned when on the same row as an input. If the button wraps around to the next row it resumes it's normal height (by default seems to be set as 36px). Not the most elegant solution but it's probably the best I've found so far.