# Material buttons are different height

Tags: html, css, angular

I'm working on an angular app where I have mostly two classes of buttons, primary and warn.  They have basically the same styles applied in the default stylesheet. However, the primary button (on the right in the screenshot below) is 1.5px taller, which is a small difference but makes the buttons look slightly off kilter. I tried to force both of them to have the same height, but that doesn't work. What would cause this?

[image]

styles and template:

```css
button:disabled {
    color: var(--text-disabled) !important;
    background-color: var(--basic-button-bg) !important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%) !important;
    cursor: default;
    border: 0 !important;
}

.primary:not([disabled]) {
    background-color: var(--basic-button-bg) !important;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 20%) !important;
    outline: 0;
    color: var(--basic-button-color) !important;
    border: 0 !important;
}

.warn:not([disabled]) {
    background-color: var(--warn-button-bg) !important;
    color: var(--warn-button-color) !important;
    outline: 0;
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<button
    i18n
    i18n-aria-label
    mat-raised-button
    border-right
    type="warn"
    class="warn"
    aria-label="close"
    (click)="cancelCreateReport()"
>
    Cancel
</button>
<button
    mat-raised-button
    type="primary"
    class="primary"
    (click)="createAndOpenReport()"
>
    <b i18n>Create</b>
</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried `box-sizing: border-box;`?

Comment: I hadn't but I tried it now. Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: try leaving the border as is(i.e. dont apply 0 size), but set `border-color: transparent`

Comment: The code snippet does not show any difference in height between the two buttons. You should try to temporarily remove everything non-essential from the code (do it bit by bit, so you can spot if anything specific causes your issue), and please add any other (possibly global) CSS that would apply to the buttons or their surroundings to the snippet. Use the browser's devtools (side tab: Layout) to check the height of the buttons and see where the extra comes from.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65416690/angular-material-how-to-make-button-same-height-as-input?rq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65416690/angular-material-how-to-make-button-same-height-as-input?rq=1

Comment: With the provided code it's not possible to determine the cause of the problem. The only difference I see is the `<b>` tag in the primary button. Check if there are any styles applied to that element that could cause the shift. Or try removing it temporarily to see if that fixes it.

Comment: check the answer over here[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65416690/angular-material-how-to-make-button-same-height-as-input?rq=1)